# Nested routers: parent routing works, child router no

Tags: angular, angular-routing

in Angular 8 I created an application with a main routing and inside the main routing there is a component with another child routing.

I have several problems: when I insert an existing path, the url appears to be correct, but the component is not shown, whereas if I insert a wrong url the 404 redirect comes into effect.

**Parent routing works, while child routing does not.**

Another problem I find is in the links, I can't insert in the link "father/son-name", only the son name appears. Manually entering the name of the father appears to me: "father/father/son".

I am attaching the code below

App.Routing.Module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent, loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m=>m.MainModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

  {path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},

  //THIS REDIRECT TO HOME
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Main.Routing.Module.TS

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: ColumnChartComponent,  children:[
    {path: 'pie', component: PieChartComponent},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: LayoutDashboardComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in parent component html?

Comment: Yes, i use <router-outlet></router-outlet>  both in the father and in the son.

I also created a navbar inside the parent router and want it to have child router links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't have a lazy-loaded route (your loadChildren()) and besides that a component in that route string. So please change

```
{path: 'main', component: MainComponent, loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m=>m.MainModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

to:

```
{path: 'main', loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m=>m.MainModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

Comment: I solved this problem. I can't add routerlinks. The link is formed as follows: "/ son". If I add the father by hand it becomes "/ father / father / child". I don't understand why the father duplicates himself

Comment: Could you please specify the url you receive?